# HTML5 Input tag : what if max,min,step do not fit with each other

Tags: html

Let's say you had a job to provide the user with a `<input>` as this:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="11" step="3" value="1"></input>
```

the result would be increased as this sequence : 1,4,7,10,(13).

you can never see "13" in the box because this number exceeds the maximum value it allows("11"). The max value you can get in this box is 10.

But what if the maximum number you want to show to the user is 11, as specified in your code ?

the expected sequence is like this : 1,4,7,10,11

How to make it ?

Thanks.

EDIT :
Here's a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/lookof/tLjw2bu3/) for the question.

Comment: @Satya, I didn't set this post properly at the time of your writing. see it again please. And here is the [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/lookof/tLjw2bu3/) for the snippet.

Comment: did you get a chance to input number using up arrow , I just tried it gave me all numbers till 11 , stepping 1 at a time

Comment: @Satya, stepping 1 is no doubt correct but what I'm asking for is stepping 3. the core idea here is the span of the stepping doesn't fit the proper unit for (max - min).

Comment: If any of the posted answers solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielRippstein, I'm very sorry about this! I was absent from the computer in past a few days. Now it's done. Thanks everyone~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible using straight HTML5.

There's no HTML5 number feature that increments by 3s and switch to 1s near the last number. HTML rarely deviates from its established rules, no matter what our needs are. And `step` has pretty strict rules with no similar HTML5 alternatives. You will have to use Javascript or a `<select>` dropdown.

**Easy Imperfect Solution**

You can use some Javascript to make this happen. This example uses jQuery in a `ready` event:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var $input = $(this), val = $input.val();
    if (val == 13) {
        $input.attr("step","1");
        $input.val(11);
    } else if (val == 10) {
        $input.attr("step","3");
    } else if (val == 12) {
        $input.val(11);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fpm21ej2/1/

There is a flash of the incorrect number "13" right before it changes to "11". I don't know of an event that would intercept this faster though, making this solution imperfect.

**Harder Better Solution**

Create a custom text field to mimick this incrementing behavior, but using your special number sequence. That means take a number box, add in some up/down buttons (possibly with sprite images), use Javascript to bind them to events that increment this as expected, and validate against the user entering invalid numbers (use the HTML5 `pattern` attribute).

That will probably take some work, and it needs a bit more time than most of us can volunteer here at StackOverflow. But this should be possible.

**Easy Better Solution**

Use a `<select>` dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

The step attribute respects the max, but also restricts the input. If you need more flexibility, try this:

```
<input list="numbers">

<datalist id="numbers">
  <option value="1">
  <option value="4">
  <option value="7">
  <option value="10">
  <option value="11">
</datalist>
```

On second thought, that's not great - I would just use the good old-fashioned select tag:

```
  <select>
    <option>1<option>
    <option>4<option>
    <option>7<option>
    <option>10<option>
    <option>11<option>
  </select>
```

to get closer to your example. If your data set is contrived to demonstrate a point, these alternatives can be generated programmatically jsut as easy as the one in your example.